# Most Probable Average Marks

Tags: probability, average

There is a class of **40** students. A professor conducted a quiz on which consisted of **10** Multiple Choice Questions. Each question had **4** options, out of which **only one** is correct. Each question carried **1** mark and there was no negative marking. What is the most probable average marks of this class? (Considering that students have no clue about the questions and they do not copy from each other).

Comment: What did you try till now? Sounds pretty much like a binomial distribution.

Comment: I am able to conclude that if the class consisted of only one student then most probable mark is 2. (Using binomial distribution).

Comment: This question is seriously incomplete. Surely those students have learnt _something_ from their professor? If not, you have to say so.

Comment: @TonyK: Hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with $n$ i.i.d random variables $x_i \in \{0,1\}$. Let $p$ be the probability for $x_i$ to take value 1. The probability for $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = k$ will be given by the formula $\binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$ .

Let $K$ be the most probable value of $k$.

By comparing the probability for the $K$ and $K+1$ term, we have:

$$\begin{align}
& \binom{n}{K} p^{K} (1-p)^{n-K} \ge \binom{n}{K+1} p^{K+1} (1-p)^{n-K-1}\\
\implies & 1 \ge \frac{n-K}{K+1} \frac{p}{1-p}\\
\implies & K \ge (n+1)p - 1
\end{align}$$

By compariing the probability for the $K$ and $K-1$ term, we have:

$$\begin{align}
& \binom{n}{K} p^{K} (1-p)^{n-K} \ge \binom{n}{K-1} p^{K-1} (1-p)^{n-K+1}\\
\implies & 1 \ge \frac{K}{n-K+1} \frac{1-p}{p}\\
\implies & (n+1)p \ge K
\end{align}$$

This means in general, the most probable value of $k$ is sandwiched between $(n+1)p - 1$ and $(n+1)p$.

Back to our question. Since we have $40$ students, each is going to take $10$ questions, we have $n = 400$ and $p =\frac{1}{4}$. Furthermore, if $X$ is the average mark for the whole class, $k = 40 X$.
This means the probability distribution for $X$ is given by:
$$\binom{400}{40X} \left(\frac14\right)^{40X} \left(\frac34\right)^{400 - 40X}$$

Using above bound, we have:

$$99.25 = (n+1)p - 1\le K \le (n+1)p = 100.25 \implies K = 100 \implies X = 2.5$$

By brute force computation, the most probable average mark is indeed 2.500.

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{avg. mark} & \text{probablity}\\
\hline\\
2.400 & 0.041900165340674\\
2.425 & 0.043771994032869\\
2.475 & 0.045871413522661\\
\color{red}{2.500} & \color{red}{0.046024318234403}\\
2.525 & 0.045568631915251\\
2.550 & 0.044526212230915\\
2.575 & 0.042941136714604\\
2.600 & 0.040876658987940\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: An interesting problem is to find the answer for general N, where N is the number of students. Any hints?

Comment: Let $M$ be the number of students, then $n = 10M$ and $(n+1)p$ is not an integer. so $K = \lfloor(10M+1)p\rfloor$ and $X = \frac{\lfloor(10M+1)p\rfloor}{M}$.